# js: trigger function after a bunch of events were called

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, prototype

I need to call a function at the end of a few events. So let's say I have 9 click listeners, 10 bluer listeners, some key up/down listeners etc.

A solution would be to modify all and add the function call.

But this is... well... lame.

Is there anyway I can add that call on all events at once (and any future defined events)?

Maybe extend events somehow?

Comment: Could you tell what result you are expecting? Sounds like an XY problem. Are these events handler bound to same element or e.g the 9 click listeners are for 9 different elements? Any jsFiddle?

Comment: If it's only for some of the event handlers on the page how do you identify which ones?

Comment: @A. Wolff Imagine I want to do something like this: When an event was triggered, I show an alert saying "event X triggered". Regardless on event.

Answer (score 1):

Misinterpreted the question. I'm leaving this answer here as a reference, although it doesn't trigger on all events.

---

I would use promises for this. i.e: using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and an event counter:

```
   var deferred = Q.defer();

   ...
   var allEventsRequired = { ev1 : false, ev2: false };
   function tryToResolvePromise() {
       for(var k in allEventsRequired){
           if( !allEventsRequired[k] ) return;
       }
       deferred.resolve();
   }
   ...
   function markEventAsFired(name) { 
         allEventsRequired[name] = true; 
         tryToResolvePromise(); 
   }
   ...

   deferred.promise.then(function() { ... this will trigger when all events got fired ... } );
```

Call `markEventAsFired( name )` from where each of your events are firing. And if you need any new one in the future just add it's name to the map `allEventsRequired`. Don't forget to initialize them as false.

Comment: Will take a look into it, didn't use Q b4. +1 4 help tho :).

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask how to do something after _any_ event, not wait until all events have occurred and then do something.

Comment: I agree with nnnnn, it's a totally different thing.

Comment: Makes sense I'll leave the question as it is as a reference, but mark it as misdirected